# On windows 64 and access 10, application.quit result into "reserved error"

Tags: windows, ms-access, vba, windows64

I am facing a problem with win64 while on win 32 everything is fine. On access Vba I have a simple function to close the db: application.quit
While it works on win32 access 2007, it prompt the error "reserved error" on win64 access 10/16.

Do you have any idea why it doesn't work?

Thank you

Comment: Windows x64 or MS-Access x64?

Comment: Please share more details. `Application.Quit` should work on both 32-bits and 64-bits Windows and Office. Possibly, there are some VBA objects or references open that make Access unable to quit. Try to make your question [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Does Application.Quit work on the same PC on a blank database? Does it work on your database outside of the sub/function you're using it in?)

Comment: Sorry to not being clear, my problem is that in an access database used either on windows 32 and windows 64, the application.quit function works only on windows 32.

Comment: The version of access used are ms access 2007 in win 32 and ms access 2010/2016 on win64. Actually on a blank database the function works.. plus in the normal db I also added a form to consider the idle time of an user, it is an hidden form with a time event attached.. but I cannot understand how it could impact.. even disabling warnings the pop up still shows..